# Creating a drop down list with formulas assigned to the drop down Item

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can I create a drop down list in excel with items that correspond to formulas?  So that if someone selects a certain item  in that list a formula will correspond to that selection?

Comment: Where is it that you want the formula?

Comment: There is a sum total column on the left of the sheet and There are about 8 columns for budget numbered 1-8 to the right and I need formulas to be associated to each column so if a person chooses the sum of 1 column that will show but if they chose another column (say 2, 3, etc) the sum formula on the left will show for that column.

Comment: This might start you off, =SUM(OFFSET(A1:A3,0,E1)), assuming a range in A1:C3 and a dropdown in E1 with options 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dave in a Comment, the answer is Yes. To be more specific without a detailed requirement I have created an example where hours are input into B3:F5, the dropdown list is in G1 (driven by B1:F1) and G2 contains an HLOOKUP formula to convert the number chosen into a day of the week. The formula in G3:G5 happens to be:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B3:"&CHAR(65+G$1)&ROW()))
```

which in turn from G3 to G5 sums the standard hours up to and including the chosen day, those plus overtime, and those plus overtime and time off.

[image: SO2544890 example]